# soapUI - Parse JSON Response containing arrays

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, groovy, soapui

Given the following JSON response from a previous test step (request) in soapUI:

```js
{
  "AccountClosed": false,
  "AccountId": 86270,
  "AccountNumber": "2915",
  "AccountOwner": 200000000001,
  "AccountSequenceNumber": 4,
  "AccountTotal": 6,
  "ActiveMoneyBeltSession": true,
  "CLMAccountId": "",
  "CustomerName": "FRANK",
  "Lines": [{
    "AndWithPreviousLine": false,
    "IngredientId": 10000025133,
    "OrderDestinationId": 1,
    "PortionTypeId": 1,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "QuantityAsFraction": "1",
    "SentToKitchen": true,
    "TariffPrice": 6,
    "Id": 11258999068470003,
    "OriginalRingUpTime": "2014-10-29T07:37:38",
    "RingUpEmployeeName": "Andy Bean",
    "Seats": []
  }, {
    "Amount": 6,
    "Cashback": 0,
    "Change": 0,
    "Forfeit": 0,
    "InclusiveTax": 1,
    "PaymentMethodId": 1,
    "ReceiptNumber": "40/1795",
    "Tip": 0,
    "Id": 11258999068470009,
    "Seats": []
  }],
  "MoaOrderIdentifier": "A2915I86270",
  "OutstandingBalance": 0,
  "SaveAccount": false,
  "ThemeDataRevision": "40",
  "TrainingMode": false
}
```

I have the following groovy script to parse the information from the response:

```js
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

//Define Variables for each element on JSON Response
String AccountID, AccountClosed, AccountOwner, AccountSeqNumber, AccountTotal, ActMoneyBelt
String CLMAccountID, ThemeDataRevision, Lines, MoaOrderIdentifier, OutstandingBalance, SaveAccount, TrainingMode, CustName, AccountNumber
String AndWithPreviousLine, IngredientId, OrderDestinationId, PortionTypeId, Quantity, SentToKitchen, TariffPrice, Id, OriginalRingUpTime, RingUpEmployeeName, Seats
int AccSeqNumInt
def responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("ReopenAcc").getPropertyValue("response")
  // Create JsonSlurper Object to parse the response
def Response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)
  //Parse each element from the JSON Response and store in a variable
AccountClosed = Response.AccountClosed
AccountID = Response.AccountId
AccountNumber = Response.AccountNumber
AccountOwner = Response.AccountOwner
AccountSeqNumber = Response.AccountSequenceNumber
AccountTotal = Response.AccountTotal
ActMoneyBelt = Response.ActiveMoneyBeltSession
CLMAccountID = Response.CLMAccountId
CustName = Response.CustomerName
Lines = Response.Lines
  /*Lines Variables*/
AndWithPreviousLine = Response.Lines.AndWithPreviousLine
IngredientId = Response.Lines.IngredientId
OrderDestinationId = Response.Lines.OrderDestinationId
PortionTypeId = Response.Lines.PortionTypeId
Quantity = Response.Lines.Quantity
SentToKitchen = Response.Lines.SentToKitchen
TariffPrice = Response.Lines.TariffPrice
Id = Response.Lines.Id
OriginalRingUpTime = Response.Lines.OriginalRingUpTime
RingUpEmployeeName = Response.Lines.RingUpEmployeeName
Seats = Response.Lines.Seats
  /*End Lines Variables*/
MoaOrderIdentifier = Response.MoaOrderIdentifier
OutstandingBalance = Response.OutstandingBalance
SaveAccount = Response.SaveAccount
ThemeDataRevision = Response.ThemeDataRevision
TrainingMode = Response.TrainingMode
```

As you can see above there is an element (Array) called "Lines". I am looking to get the individual element value within this array. My code above when parsing the elements is returning the following:

----------------Lines Variables----------------

```js
INFO: AndWithPreviousLine: [false, null]
INFO: IngredientId: [10000025133, null]
INFO: OrderDestinationId: [1, null]
INFO: PortionTypeId: [1, null]
INFO: Quantity: [1.0, null]
INFO: SentToKitchen: [true, null]
INFO: TariffPrice: [6.0, null]
INFO: Id: [11258999068470003, 11258999068470009]
INFO: OriginalRingUpTime: [2014-10-29T07:37:38, null]
INFO: RingUpEmployeeName: [Andy Bean, null]
INFO: Seats: [[], []]
```

How can i get the required element from the above, also note the the 2 different data contracts contain the same element "ID". Is there a way to differenciate between the 2.

any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Edit this question please, it's not readable at the moment.

Comment: Please let me know on what information you need clarified, i do not know how to make it clearer.

Comment: There's no need to make it clearer probably but formatted well - maybe I wasn't to precise. Currently the code isn't readable e.g. json.

Comment: Sure will do this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Lines" in the Response can be treated as a simple list of maps.

```
Response["Lines"].each { println it }

[AndWithPreviousLine:false, Id:11258999068470003, IngredientId:10000025133, OrderDestinationId:1, OriginalRingUpTime:2014-10-29T07:37:38, PortionTypeId:1, Quantity:1, QuantityAsFraction:1, RingUpEmployeeName:Andy Bean, Seats:[], SentToKitchen:true, TariffPrice:6]
[Amount:6, Cashback:0, Change:0, Forfeit:0, Id:11258999068470009, InclusiveTax:1, PaymentMethodId:1, ReceiptNumber:40/1795, Seats:[], Tip:0]
```

The Response is just one huge map, with the Lines element a list of maps.

Using groovysh really helps here to interactively play with the data, i did the following commands after starting a "groovysh" console:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
t = new File("data.json").text
r = new JsonSlurper().parse(t)
r
r["Lines"]
r["Lines"][0]
```

etc

Edit: In response to your comment, here's a better way to get the entry with a valid AndWithPreviousLine value.

```
myline = r["Lines"].find{it.AndWithPreviousLine != null}
myline.AndWithPreviousLine
>>> false
myline.IngredientId
>>> 10000025133
```

If you use `findAll` instead of `find` you'll get an array of maps and have to index them, but for this case there's only 1 and `find` gives you the first whose condition is true.

By using `Response["Lines"].AndWithPreviousLine [0]` you're assuming AndWithPreviousLine exists on each entry, which is why you're getting nulls in your lists. If the json responses had been reversed,  you'd have to use a different index of [1], so using `find` and `findAll` will work better for you than assuming the index value.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the above worked for me and can pull the relevent element from a list e.g. log.info (Response["Lines"].AndWithPreviousLine [0])

Comment: @blader what you're doing with `Response["Lines"].AndWithPreviousLine[0]` is assuming that all your Lines have this element, and taking first, as you can see, the only common element is the Id field. If you want the entry that has a non-null AndWithPreviousLine value, you're better off using `Response["Lines"].find {it.AndWithPreviousLine != null}`, which will give you the whole map entry for the one with that data in it, add `.AndWithPreviousLine` to the end of that to get its value. I'll update my answer to make this more clear.